# Passing 3rd Party Access Token in redirection URL of 3rd Party Website

Tags: url-redirection, token, url

I am integrating a website with 3rd party API. The 3rd party site allows me to generate Access Token by using Client Key/Client Secret.

In one of the pages, I need to redirect to 3rd party site 's web page, which needs an AccessToken to validate if the page is redirected from the valid client or not.

The Access Token which I am passing in the URL is the same Access Token though which I can call 3rd party App 's other APIs.

Though redirection from my site to their site will happen only for authenticated users and access token will be valid for an hour only, I think it is a security risk because if a logged-in user is a Technical User, he can use the Access Token to call other APIs from 3rd Party API within an hour.

Can someone suggest, is it recommended to pass the Access Token in the redirection URL?

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Shukla